# Error made if we consider the whole globe as the coordinate chart?.

Tags: manifolds, intuition, visualization

I was looking at [this article at mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoordinateChart.html)
where it has mentioned -

"This coordinate chart is not valid on the whole globe, since it doesn't give unique coordinates at the north or south pole (which way is east from the north pole?)."

I could not understand this logic/ any motivation ?

What error will we make if we consider the whole globe as the coordinate chart?.

Also from Wiki -

"As for the circle, one may define one chart that covers the whole sphere excluding one point. Thus two charts are sufficient, but the sphere cannot be covered by a single chart."

This example is historically significant, as it has motivated the terminology; it became apparent that the whole surface of the Earth cannot have a plane representation consisting of a single map (also called "chart", see nautical chart), and therefore one needs atlases for covering the whole Earth surface.

Any Mathematical visualization to this or a counter example would be helpful?.

Comment: The error is the premise in the question, "What error will we make if we consider the whole globe as the coordinate chart?" A coordinate chart on the sphere $\Bbb S^2$ is a homeomorphism from some open $U \subset \Bbb S^2$ onto its image. For the usual map $\psi$ that assigns a latitude and longitude (i.e. a point in $\Bbb R^2$) to the corresponding point on the sphere, if $\psi(x) = \textrm{north pole}$ for some $x$ in an open set $V$, then it also maps infinitely many points in $V$ to the north pole. So $\psi$ doesn't even have an inverse and so is not the inverse of a coordinate chart map.

Comment: We can see that this is not just a matter of a defect in the latitude-longitude system but rather a feature of the topology of the sphere: A coordinate chart that covered all of $\Bbb S^2$ would be a homeomorphism from $\Bbb S^2$ to an open set in $\Bbb R^2$, but the former is compact and the latter is not, so there is no such map.

Comment: The comments above give perfectly sound mathematical answers, I just want to add an easy (if much less complete) explanation: the longitude lines all go through the north and south pole, so you cannot say at what longitude they are (in this sense, the poles don't have a unique east-west coordinate).

Comment: Very Nice! It would be nice if you could post them as answers,

Comment: also can I invite you all to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73238/differentiable-manifolds 
 Differentiable Manifolds chat room? it would be nice if we can discuss this all..